# How to provide an alternate library path for one application only?

Tags: linux, libraries, slackware

After installing the infinality font configs and recompiling freetype with some patches wine won't recognize freetype anymore.
I've tried statically linking only freetype by modifying a slackbuild script but that did not work out.
Plus, it seems static linking is considered harmful.

What would I need to do to tell wine to use the vanilla version of the library under a different name, perhaps?

Would LD_PRELOAD work?